# проверка нахождения в строке фрагмена регулярного выражения python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
Очень хочется что то вроде 
string = 10.09.2019

#есть подазрения что выражение не верно
#но суть вопроса в другом
reg = r'\d[.]\d[.]\d'

#хочу вот такое
print(string.contains(reg))
>>true\false
#но нечего такого я ненашол
```

Нашёл через импорт **re** но там я так понял все функции ищут строки, 
а не выдают тру или фолс.... может все такие есть что то подобное...
короткая запись в обмен на булево значение

Comment: Только функции если ничего не нашли возвращают None который в if будет приведен к false. А если они что то нашли то они вернут какое то значение, которое разумеется будет приведено к true. так что смело можно писать `if re.search...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

pat = r"\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\b"

print(bool(re.search(pat, '10.09.2019')))
#True
print(bool(re.search(pat, '10.09.219.10')))
#False
print(bool(re.search(pat, '10.09.19')))
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так напишите метод сами. Что-то типа такого:

```
import re
a = '10.09.2019'
b = '10.09.219.10'
reg = r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"

class ipfind():
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
    def contains(self, reg):        
        self.reg = reg        
        res = re.findall(reg, self.ip)
        if res:
            return True
        else:
            return False

c = ipfind(a)
print(c.contains(reg))
d = ipfind(b)
print(d.contains(reg))
```

На выходе будет:

```
False
True
```